# Talend studio isNumeric()

Tags: java, talend

I am learning talend open studio and I want to put this line of code :

`boolean numeric = isNumeric(input_row.id);`

In `tjavaroW`, but when I run the job it throws me an error:

> isNumeric is an undefined method

. Please can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're looking for an `isNumeric()` implementation, see [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1102891/5221149).

Comment: A method in java is always part of a class. In which class is method `isNumeric()` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check.. if the input is numeric or not using below piece of code at *tJavaRow*

```
boolean isNumeric=true;
try{
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(input_row.id);
} catch(Exception ex){
    isNumeric = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Talend you must indicate the Library you are using.
For instance : StringUtils.isNumeric.